# Matlab figure flashes back and forth between black&white and color

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to display a color disparity map, but it first displays black and white until I do 'colormap jet' then it's in color.

How can black and white image be suppressed?

```
            imshow(disparityMap, DisparityRange ); 
            title('DISPARITY MAP');
            colormap jet;
```

Comment: Does `imshow(disparityMap, DisparityRange, 'colormap', jet)` work?

Comment: @excaza - Blah lol.  I didn't see this comment.  Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @rayryeng nah, I can't test right now so I didn't know if it would work

Comment: @excaza - It works! lol

Comment: @DougNull - did I answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Specify the `colormap` parameter to `imshow`.

```
imshow(disparityMap, DisparityRange, 'colormap', jet);
```

## Example use

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(im, [60,200], 'colormap', hsv);
```

We get this image:

[image]