# how to refresh a Matlab window and leaving it where it was in the Z-order

Tags: windows, matlab, matlab-figure

My script on Windows 7 has multiple matlab figures (windows).
When I periodically re-display the disparity figure, it always brings it to the front of the other windows.  I want to leave it where it was, in the Z order.

```
                if isempty( disparity_map_figure)   
                    disparity_map_figure = figure('Name', 'DISPARITY MAP');
                else
                    figure( disparity_map_figure );
                end
                imshow(disparity_map, DisparityRange, 'colormap', jet );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of recreating the image object each time with `imshow`, get a handle to the image object created by `imshow` the first time, and then update only its `'CData'` property with the new values. That will modify the image without affecting the figure's z-order.

Here's an example:

```
f = figure; %// create figure
data = rand(200,300); %// initial data
figure(f); %// make figure current
h = imshow(data); %// create image in that figure with initial data
%// Place here code that sets figure z-order; for example by creating other figures
for n = 1:10
    pause(.1) %// include a pause for better visualization
    data = rand(200,300); %// create new data
    set(h, 'CData', data); %// update image data without affecting figure z-order
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
                if isempty( disparity_map_figure)   
                    disparity_map_figure = figure('Name', 'DISPARITY MAP');
                else
                    set(groot,'CurrentFigure',disparity_map_figure);

                    %figure( disparity_map_figure );
                end
                imshow(disparity_map, DisparityRange, 'colormap', jet );
```

Comment: This answer is just code and poor quality. You should at least explain what you did and why/how it works so that it might benefit others.

Comment: Use Luis's answer as a model for future answers.  Code dumping isn't productive and doesn't help anyone understand the choices you made and how the code works.

Comment: BTW, I see you have used the answer from your previous question in your answer to help you solve your problem... yet you haven't acknowledged whether I have helped you or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975182/matlab-figure-flashes-back-and-forth-between-blackwhite-and-color - it'd be nice to get an accept for the answer that I gave you if it helped.  Using the answer I wrote to help you and not acknowledging that it did help you isn't really conducive to me answering any further questions that you bring up (if I have the potential of answering them).